# Quantum state of two polarization-entangled photons passing an experimental assembly (PBS and polarizing filter)

Tags: quantum-entanglement, polarization

I'm wondering if anyone can help me understand how the quantum state of two polarization-entangled photons evolve in the following case.

Suppose you have two polarization-entangled photons A and B in the following Bell state :

\begin{equation}
\Phi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigl(\left|H_{A},H_{B}\right\rangle + \left| V_{A},V_{B}\right\rangle\bigr)
\end{equation}

Suppose the photon A passes through a polarizing beam splitter oriented at the +45 angle.

As far as I have understood, the resulting state is as follows, whether the photon A goes one path or the other (let's say up path or down path) :

\begin{equation}
\Phi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigl(\frac{1}{2}\bigl(\left|H_{A} + V_{A}\right\rangle\bigr) \otimes \left|H_{B}\right\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\bigl(\left|H_{A} + V_{A}\right\rangle\bigr) \otimes \left| V_{B}\right\rangle\bigr)\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\Phi=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\bigl(\left|H_{A},H_{B}\right\rangle + \left|V_{A},H_{B}\right\rangle + \left|H_{A},V_{B}\right\rangle + \left|V_{A},V_{B}\right\rangle \bigr)\end{equation}

What I understand here is that some kind of partial decoherence occurred.

Now suppose that photon A taking the PBS up path is directed to pass through a vertical polarizer filter (i.e., not a PBS : Here we are measuring it), again, as far as I have understood it, the resulting state is as follows :

\begin{equation}
\Phi=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\bigl(\left|H_{A}\rangle + |V_{A}\right\rangle\bigr) \otimes + \bigl(\left|H_{A},H_{B}\right\rangle +\left|V_{A},H_{B}\right\rangle + \left|H_{A},V_{B}\right\rangle + \left|V_{A},V_{B}\right\rangle \bigr)\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\Phi=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(\left| H_{B}\rangle + | V_{B}\right\rangle)
\end{equation}

What I understand here is that the photons are not entangled anymore, which is logical because we measured one of them. Moreover, the photon B has one chance out of two to be horizontaly or verticaly polarized.

Am I right or not ???

Thanks a lot in advance for your help !

Comment: If a factory makes red and blue poker chips and the factory always makes a red followed by a blue ...... and if you stand at the output of the machine and you get a red one .... then you know the next one is blue ...i.e the production is entangled. Now if you take that red poker chip and paint it green ..... do you still know if the next chip is blue? Of course you do ..... its the same for entangled photons.

Comment: Sorry but I have never read such an abstruse answer.
This is absolutely no help to me.
Moreover, I wonder if you're not mocking at me...

Comment: Probably I do not fully understand your question.  The fact that might be important to you is that  ...... once an entangled pair is made the 2 photons are entirely independent of each other .... you  can do whatever you want to either photon and it will NOT effect the other.  All we know is that if we look at one then we knew the state of the other one at creation.  Unfortunately there were many incorrect thought experiments/articles that tried to imply by measuring one particle we changed the state of the other after creation... these were false.

Comment: Hum... Entanglement precisely implies that each photon cannot be described with an individual state. This is not what I would call "independance"...Anyway, my point is that, as far as I have correctly understood all that, the state of photon B remains unknown since the state of photon A remains unknown (i.e. since photon A has not still been measured).

Comment: ...and coming back to my "experience", if photons A & B are originally in the Bell state I wrote : If photon A passes through a polarizing beam splitter oriented at the +90° angle, it is a measurement, and entanglement vanishes BUT if photon A passes through a polarizing beam splitter oriented at the +45° angle, part of the entanglement remains.

Comment: Yes we could have 2 atoms/electrons or 2 quantum circuits that are in a "true" entangled state, they are typically in very close proximity to each other etc.  BUT the typical photon experiment you describe is NOT truly entangled in this way after creation .... but yes the photons were created in an entangled process and that's as far as it goes.